# EventToCommandBehavior RelativeSource in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono

Why it is not work?

```
<Editor
    Text="{Binding OptionText}">
    <Editor.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="Focused"
            Command="{Binding CheckEditorViewCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:SurveyViewModel}}}" />
    </Editor.Behaviors>
</Editor>
```

I get crash app when I try open page with this xaml code.

> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
> EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid
> due to the current state of the object. 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt
> (28519):   at Xamarin.Forms.Binding.ApplyRelativeSourceBinding
> (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject targetObject,
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty) [0x00041] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:158  01-14 07:50:43.611
> F/mono-rt (28519):   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0
> (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519):   at
> Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000]
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36
> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519):   at
> Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519):   at
> Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
> native__this) [0x00008] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84
> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519):   at
> Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V
> (_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz)
> [0x00005] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22
> 01-14 07:50:43.611 F/mono-rt (28519):   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
> Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(intptr,intptr)

When I drop this is cod, page will work.
I have been understood that problem in binding way, but I don't understand how do it right.

Comment: Please add the code of `SurveyViewModel`, if you are convenient, you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can help me check your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with that binding approach:

```
<Editor
    Text="{Binding OptionText}">
        <Editor.Behaviors>
            <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="TextChanged"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=SurveyPageCustomName},
                Path=BindingContext.CheckEditorViewCommand}" />
        </Editor.Behaviors>
</Editor>
```

I don't why, but this is `Command="{Binding CheckEditorViewCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:SurveyViewModel}}}"` not work for behavior but work for `TapGestureRecognizer`. It is confused me.